# How to select all UITextview content by hold and show Copy option by programmatically iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview, textselection

Am working for am message based iPhone app. In my application i have loaded the message content in UITextView and added an UIImage on UITextView.

Now i want to **select all UITextView content by holding** UITextView and **show the Copy option** to the user. Currently when the user `hold UITextView some of the content only selecting`.

Any one please help me to do this? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

In UITableView `CellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate

```
    customMessageTextView = [[MessageTextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    customMessageTextView.tag = 100;
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15]; 
    customMessageTextView.font = font;
    customMessageTextView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    customMessageTextView.delegate = self;
    customMessageTextView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:customMessageTextView];
    [customMessageTextView sizeToFit]; 

    for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in customMessageTextView.gestureRecognizers) 
    {
        if ([recognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]])
        {
            recognizer.enabled = NO;
        }
    }


    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *myLongPressRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(selectAllTextFromCustomMessageTextView)]; 
    [customMessageTextView addGestureRecognizer:myLongPressRecognizer];
    [myLongPressRecognizer release];
```

UILongPressGestureRecognizer action:

```
-(void) selectAllTextFromCustomMessageTextView
{
    NSLog(@"Select All Text Messages");
    customMessageTextView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0, customMessageTextView.text.length);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to disable the standard behaviour when holding in a `UITextView` (i.e. the magnifying glass, etc.). Perhaps you have even disabled the editing option. If so you should just add an `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to your `UITextView`. You might have to disable the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` which is built into `UITextView` by default. You can find a way to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3893841/569507).

Then in your `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` action method you simply select all the text in the view:

```
[textView selectAll:self];
```

Notice that this will bring up the **Copy/Cut/Paste** menu. However, if your text view does in fact have user editing disabled the menu will only contain **Copy**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am trying your instructions. I will let you know the result. Thanks again.

Comment: It is not working for me. I will post my code. Could you please help me? Thanks.

Comment: You are right, setting the `selectedRange` property does not work. I have updated my answer with a method that should work (I have tested it this time).

Comment: that selectall: does not work, neither selectrange it must be for something else, who knows please post.