# how to create press and hold gesture and open new menu in UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview

I create one app that has UITextView in self. I want create one menu that when press and hold had this identify : select text from ... to ... - highlight - one part for show alert (when click on it show me choose sentence with alert) but I don't know how to do it?
now when I press and hold gesture in UITextView show me popover menu that has : (copy - select all - define) I want remove this menu and put my menu in it.

Can I do it? please help me

Answer (score 0):

To remove the current menu when you do a long press:
[How to intercept long press on UITextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893387/how-to-intercept-long-press-on-uitextview)

To create your own menu:
[iPhone/iPad context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833184/iphone-ipad-context-menu)